# Open file with multiple thread dumps in JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

I have a `.log` file with thread dumps coming from one of our production environments. Inside there are thread dumps saved every 5 minutes for whole day.

This file can be opened with `IBM Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer`. When I try to open it in `JProfiler` (after renaming it `.log` -> `.hprof`) it says that format is incorrect.

Does someone know if it's possible to open multi thread dump files in `JProfiler`  ?

Answer (score 1):

As of JProfiler 13, `.log` files from the IBM JVM cannot be opened in JProfiler. HPROF is a different format.